# Downloading and Installing Latest Version of KILE

Tags: programming, administration, kile

In the [TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) group of Stack Exchange, I posed a question about the [versions of TeXLive under Ubuntu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27721/versions-of-texlive-under-ubuntu).  As I have installed the latest version of TeXLive under Ubuntu, I want to be able to use it when running an integrated development environment like KILE.  Though a solution (and fix) was presented on the [KILE Support Discussion Group](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kile/forums/forum/292014/topic/1700810), it involves downloading, compiling and installing the latest version of KILE.

In order to compile KILE, I need:

1. KDE Libraries 4.2 or better
2. Qt 4.5 or better
3. Cmake 2.6.2 or better
4. A recent C++ compile, for example GCC 4.4

My problem is that I can't determine what version of the KDE libraries or Qt I have installed on my system.  Note that I am running Ubuntu Version 11.04.

My question, however, is whether or not the latest version of KILE (Version 2.1) will be included in the next release of Ubuntu (i.e. Version 11.10).  If so, I could save myself the effort and grief of compiling and installing KILE.  If not, will my installing the latest version affect the Synaptic Package Manager's ability of applying any future releases/updates to KILE?

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [source page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kile) for kile, 11.04 shipped with `1:2.1.0~svn1112278beta4-2ubuntu2`, and `1:2.1.0~svn2010122beta5-1ubuntu1~natty1` is available as a backport.

11.10 already appears to have 2.1.0 final.

This fellow appears to have a PPA of Kile 2.1 so that you don't have to compile it yourself:

https://launchpad.net/~kile/+archive/stable

You can find information on how to add and use PPAs here:

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)
- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out) (And of course the usual warning about using untrusted packages)

Here's a command line snippet on how to use it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kile/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Will upgrade your kile to that version (2.1). Ubuntu automatically disables PPAs the next time you upgrade your OS and usually you'll just pick up the newest version that is available at that time.

Comment: It worked!  Once again, thank you for your help!  As a matter of course, I will report this solution back to the TeX - LaTeX group under the Stack Exchange.  BTW - Correct me if I am wrong but, would PPA be similar to Darwin Ports?

Comment: It seems that the ppa is not suitable for precide pangolin. Isn't it?

Comment: No, 2.1.0 is in 12.04 already.

Comment: @JorgeCastro In fact, it is, but I'm experiencing continuous crashes of the application. I wondered if there was some way to upgrade to Kile 2.1.2