# Kile crashes upon closing project

Tags: kile

Kile allows me to work, but it keeps crashing every time I close a project. It also crashes when I close Kile directly.

Since I need to kill the program in order to exit, I can save the individual document info but I lose the changes in project data. Therefore when Kile is restarted the same project is open, and the same documents are active.

Comment: Same here. I experienced it in 2.1.0. (currently available in repos.) Better upgrade to 2.1.2 via ppa (unfortunately not availabe for 12.04).
http://askubuntu.com/questions/60611/downloading-and-installing-latest-version-of-kile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem. There was a residual locking file from the first time Kile didn't close correctly (long time ago, probably). I hope this can help someone going through the same.

The solution to my problem was just deleting the file "myproject.kilepr.lock" (my project file is called "myproject.kilepr"). All works fine now :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in 2.1.0 which occurs in Ubuntu 12.04 (cf.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kile/+bug/994498
)

The solution apparently is to update to 2.1.2

The workaround with the .lock might has been a lucky punch - I don't have any of these files and Kile 2.1.0 crashes at every exit.